# Xcode debugger not giving any output

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a stumper.  **How can I get my Xcode debugger to provide an output under the following circumstances?**

I tried restarting my iMac.  I tried restarting Xcode. I tried restarting my simulator.

I am looking at the proper debugger panel:
[image]

I have tried "activating the debugger."
[image]

I do have code that should produce an output as well.
[image]

The app does run in the simulator.

No crash report or popover warningis provided.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried running on a device.  This is a partial answer/fix.  The debugger works when running on the device.